# How to prove a statement with two " if and only if"

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, show that $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK \subseteq KH$, if and only if $KH \subseteq HK$.

This statement confuses me. Does mean I need to prove that $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK \subseteq KH$ and also prove $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $KH \subseteq HK$?

Comment: If you have $A$ if and only if $B$ if and only if $C$ then you have to prove two things.  But you can choose how you do it.  You can prove $A$ if and only if $B$ AND prove $B$ if and only if $C$.  Or you can prove $A$ if and only if $B$ AND $A$ if and only if $C$.  Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly. You have three equivalent statements. Finally, this gives a proof that $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$. This is a standard exercise in group theory - see question $7$ in this homework [here](https://math.la.asu.edu/~helene/mat444/04s/solhwk2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove $P \iff Q \iff R$ . This mean $P\iff Q$ and also $Q \iff R$, thus this mean $P \iff R$ and $Q \iff R$ etc...

One way to prove this type of statement is proving $P \implies Q$, then $Q \implies R$, then $R \implies P$.